# how to unfreeze jupyter notebook cell output?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have machine learning going with verbose 1. I run it through the network so I could work even when I'm away. but when I open my jupyter notebook that still has cell running, the output is freeze. The output is not updating. I know it's still running but I want to know the progress. How can I unfreeze it? or can it?

**Edit**

Let's say I have a program that looping and printing every iteration (because it's the same case, freeze output) and this program take a long time but will give some output, the output cell is not updating but the website icon is still hourglass icon, not the book, and the dot on the right side of "Python 3" is active, which mean there is a process running

[image]

[image]

I use :

```
jupyter                   1.0.0            py37h03978a9_7    conda-forge
jupyter_client            7.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
jupyter_console           6.4.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.9.2            py37h03978a9_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_widgets        1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: This is a very vague question, can you provide more information about how you are running the notebook, what version you are using and what code you are running?

Comment: I edit jupyter notebook I use for my question and add some details